# large static array in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, shortest-path

I have two arrays, one is a node-node-cost array [a_node,b_node,cost] which has 8000 entries and the other one is an association of node with coordinates [node,x,y] which has around 8000 entries as well. Is it better to have a static array of these two or is it better to store these in the database and from that create an array as of performance issue?

These two array will be used to run the shortest path algorithm.

Comment: It's static?  Are you only running it once?

Comment: it will be used multiple times... maybe thousands and million of times as the algorithm will be used multiple times.. so every time the algorithm is called these arrays are used

Comment: Could you not implement the algorithm in the database using a stored proceedure or function? You're going to be blowing stuff up in php

Comment: Depending on your algorithm, chances are you'll have to load all these entries into memory anyways. So why not skip the middleman (the database) and shove the arrays in PHP code?

Comment: Also note that "static" is a tricky concept in PHP. In PHP every time a script finishes running everything that was in memory gets discarded. So the next time you load the same script - even if it's immediately after the 1st one, you'll have to load everything into memory again.

Comment: @NullUserException yes I was planning to remove the database and shove to arrays in PHP code, that's my first plan.. but will this be a pain?

Comment: @Equinox It depends on how often these arrays need to be changed.

Comment: the array value never changed... they are used as a reference to calculate the shortest path.. it's like you're traversing through an array... the value never changed, values are being accessed

Comment: @EquinoX, I believe NullUserException meant changing stored values permanently so that next time when script executes it's not what it was 2 days ago.

Comment: what do you mean by changing stored values permanently?

Comment: @EquinoX, you wrote that you have 8000 entries. Tomorrow you might have 8100 entries, after a week - 9000 entries. This means that data needs to be changed (permanently) from time to time. Or, if it does not change, you now have 8000 entries, and after a year you will still have the same 8000 entries (rather than, for example, 20'000 entries).

Comment: and that's what I am saying... today I have 8000 entries and it will always be 8000 no matter what... it doesn't change. Why are you saying that it will change? the array are used only for reference.. no insertion or deletion to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you'll probably want to use a dynamic programming solution where you calculate a small portion of the problem on each iteration and store the intermediate results which will allow you to calculate the shortest path once you are done with all of the intermediate calculations.

I would suggest storing all of your information in a database and selecting out a subset of records (maybe 100 at a time?). Calculate the intermediate information for each node and store that back to the database. If you are going to reuse this path information thousands or millions of times, you don't want to be recalculating it constantly. You'll only want to recalculate when the graph changes.

My preferred shortest path algorithm is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm and it lends itself to an efficient dynamic programming solution.

Comment: I am actually running an A* algorithm, extension of Djikstra.. and moving to a dynamic programming solution might not be possible. Maybe what I can do is to have a list of neighbors of a node stored in the database, therefore it's less computation.. what do you think?

Comment: Yes, that sounds similar to what I was imagining off the top of my head.

Comment: Other than that... what else should be moved to the database? How about the list of nodes - nodes - cost? Coordinates of nodes?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm saying you should store all of it in the database. The information should be reusable, so you can calculate it, populate your database and then select it many times.

Comment: so then this way the shortest path will do a lot of querying to the db, is this better than static array?

Comment: Again, it all depends on whether the huge array is causing problems (which it sounds like it is) and whether you can save processing time by using the stored results in the db. Queries to a local db are usually pretty darn fast. If your current implementation doesn't have a problem, then don't worry about it. If it does, then take one of the above suggestions for a solution.

Comment: I am just planning for a better approach, as of now it might not be a problem as less people are using it.. but when it grows, I want it to be scalable

Answer (score 0):

If you had tested it you would have found the answer for yourself - a lot depends on how you are populating the arrays and how often you are dereferencing elements from an existing array. The former is massively faster when the data is stored / manipulated with a database. the latter is more of a grey area - but a database can still prove faster in most cases.

(unless this is your homework, and given the number of nodes, I'd recommend considering using a non-deterministic approach - the genetic algortihm is an obvious candidate)